# Newrelic not sending data from Centos 7 (PHP)

Tags: php, linux, apache, newrelic, newrelic-platform

So I have 3 servers all setup with newrelic without issue but my most recent attempt is failing and I cannot figure out why. I have done the following.

1. Installed Repository
2. `sudo yum install newrelic-php5`
3. `sudo newrelic-install install`
4. Entered license key on install screen and then confirmed it exists in newrelic.ini inside of /etc/php.d/
5. Changed "newrelic.appname" in the newrelic.ini
6. Restarted Apache and the newrelic-daemon

All to no success. The server is Centos 7 with PHP 7.1 and Apache 2.4, any ideas on what could be wrong?

**Edit**: Here are the only things in my log files if that helps

newrelic-daemon.log

> Info: New Relic daemon version 7.0.0.186-22bc2bd494bc [listen="/tmp/.newrelic.sock" ssl=enabled startup=agent pid=30303 ppid=1 uid=0 euid=0 gid=0 egid=0 runtime="go1.7" GOMAXPROCS=4 GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64]

php-agent.log

> 2017-03-15 15:22:07.172 -0500 (30297 30297) info: New Relic 7.0.0.186 ("pipher" - "22bc2bd494bc") [daemon='/tmp/.newrelic.sock'  php='7.1.2' zts=no sapi='apache2handler' apache='2.4.6' mpm=prefork pid=30297 ppid=1 uid=0 euid=0 gid=0 egid=0 backtrace=yes startup=agent os='Linux' rel='3.10.0-514.2.2.e$
>       2017-03-15 15:22:07.173 -0500 (30297 30297) info: spawned daemon child pid=30298

Comment: It's a bit complicate to help your without some logs and some more informations.

Comment: Updated question with log info

Comment: This very well may be an SELinux problem. You might want to start here: https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/agents/php-agent/troubleshooting/data-stops-reporting-while-using-selinux#solution